# Are there good sources on Quantitative Architecture?

Tags: architecture

I've been using a basic way of scoring of bugs.  I basically rate their severity from 1 to 4 (obviously very subjective) and "tag" structures in my teams programs (classes, methods within a class, etc.).

At that point, I create a basic graph of the "hot" areas of an application.  The hot areas are where bugs are showing up the most often.

I'm guessing there are more complex techniques out there.  Can someone point me in the direction of books/articles on these techniques?

My goal is to eventually make my architecture decisions more quantitative and less based on intuition or general "best" practices guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like the sound of what you are doing - a very simple idea :)

**RE: Quantitative Architecture**

This is a good article, over on MSDN - Architecture Journal : [Evaluating Application Architecture, Quantitatively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/ff476939(en-us).aspx)

> Summary: This article describes how
>   quantitative treatment can be applied
>   to an application’s
>   architecture-evaluation process and
>   shows how a quantitative output with
>   intuitive reports will provide more
>   clarity than a qualitative output on
>   the quality of an application
>   architecture.

I'm not sure if it's what you're after but it's certainly Quantitative.
Alternatively there's [ATAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATAM).